# Javascript: Can't Set Style of Null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refactor this small chunk of code to define commonly-required variables and use them in the methods.  Why does **this.title** work but **this.dialogoverlay** does not? The commented line works, but I want to refactor as stated so I don't have to use `document.getElementById` over and over.

```
function CustomAlert(){

   this.title = "This is My Title";

   this.dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');

   this.render = function(dialog){
      // document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "block";
      this.dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('dialog-shadow').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = this.title; 
      document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;

      etc...
```

I get "Can't set style of null."

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows how and when `this.render()` is called. Most likely `this` is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: @Andreas Good catch!  Timing is the issue.  I use it in an onclick="CustomAlert('some message')".  So, you are correct.  The element dialogoverlay element does not exist when I try to set the definition.  I will convert the html onlick to the script via addEventListener and put it after document ready.

Comment: @JeffMatthews It's not about "timing". `document.getElementById()` would return `null` if an element with the given id cannot be found, hence the error message would be `Cannot ... of null`. Check the value of `this`, I guess it will be `window`

Comment: @Andreas  You are correct, Andreas.  My mistake.  The error was indeed null.  I have edited my question.  The code is fixed and now works.  You helped and didn't even know it!  ;-)

Comment: Lesson learned: be more careful when posting error messages because one word can change everything ;)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, "Why does this.title work but this.dialogoverlay does not?".

What "this" refers to depends on how you are invoking the function. I would like to quote something from http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-this/,

"A common mistake you may have is to think that this is the same in an inner function as in the outer function. The truth is that the context of the inner function depends on how it is invoked not the context of the outer function."

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` in function reference to other variable. Try use `dialog` instead `this`